# How to install Luwx/Lightly (Lightly Application Style)

Tags: plasma

*Image: Lightly Colour Scheme Alpha - available through System Settings and Pling.*

[image: Image of Lightly Colour Scheme "Alpha" - available from System Settings and Pling]

This Q/A explains how to install Lightly Application Style to KDE Plasma.

After installing you probably want to make Colour Schemes transparent, and the instructions are provided in https://github.com/Luwx/Lightly

You can also download pre-made Lightly Colour Schemes through System Settings or for example from [Pling](https://www.pling.com/u/plingsaarinen)

Comment: Hi there H2onvety - your answer is really useful but the question as written is a little confusing. I thought [Archisman Panigrahi's edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1444455/14) made it easier to understand what the question was about without changing the meaning. Perhaps you can rearrange and reword the question a little along these lines but keeping all the points you want to mention.

Comment: @Zanna Thank You for your kind words. What Paningrahi was trying to ask, is how to make  color schemes transparent, and the answer is in  https://github.com/Luwx/Lightly and it would require an own answer. This Q/A is only about installing Lightly. Would you please read if my Q is now clear enough.

Comment: Most of this question seems like it should belong in the answer - everything except the title seem like instructions.

Comment: It looks fine to me. I agree that some of the content might be more what we expect to find in the answer, but it's now clear what it's all about, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In Plasma 5.24 you can use the original instructions in [Luwx/Lightly](https://github.com/Luwx/Lightly).

If you use the original instructions in Plasma 5.25 - 5.27, Dolphin titlebar will be fully transparent - not blur as it is supposed to be.

The original instructions also do not work anymore in Arch and Manjaro Linux.

---

### Install in Plasma 5.25 - 5.27

---

### Ubuntu derivatives

(1) Install dependencies

```
sudo apt install cmake build-essential libkf5config-dev libkdecorations2-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev extra-cmake-modules libkf5guiaddons-dev libkf5configwidgets-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev gettext qt3d5-dev
```

(2) Download package from Boehs's [fork](https://github.com/boehs/Lightly)

```
git clone --single-branch --depth=1 https://github.com/boehs/Lightly.git
```

(3) (Move Lightly to a preferred location and) Inside Lightly directory create directory *build*

```
mkdir build
```

(4) Inside build directory install the package with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF ..
```

and

```
make
```

and

```
sudo make install
```

---

> P.S. Remember to uninstall previous Lightly before installing new one
> with `sudo make uninstall` in `build` directory.

### How to enable it

After installation, open System Settings, go to `Appearance -> Application Style`, and choose `Lightly`.

Then, also in `Appearence`, go to `Window Decorations` and choose `Lightly`.

You may have to logout and log back in for the changes to take effect.

---

For those interested, here is how to install it in other distros.

---

### Arch and Manjaro Linux

((1) Install `base-devel` with Manjaro Package Manager.)

(2) Install dependencies

```
sudo pacman -S breeze-icons frameworkintegration hicolor-icon-theme kdecoration kwayland cmake extra-cmake-modules git kcmutils
kdecoration qt5-declarative qt5-x11extras
```

(3) Download the package

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lightly-git
```

(4) Install the package (inside the Lightly-git directory) with

```
makepkg -si
```

OR

```
makepkg -sric
```

(to clear orphan unneeded packages - Didn’t test it myself)

---

### Other Linux distributions

I don't know.
The original instructions may or may not work.

---

---

> P.S. No blurred Dolphin titlebar still after installing everything as
> supposed? - Remember also to change Window Decorations to Lightly...

---

NOTICE:

> with Lightly application style (especially full glass Lightly),
> opening VLC Video player installed from Ubuntu repositories OR from
> Snap MAY CAUSE the Whole Plasma Session TO CRASH.
>
> ... So instead, if you are using Lightly **install VLC from Flatpak** - It works OK with Lightly.

> With MPV Video Player the blur in Plasma desktop may/will also disappear (blur in panel and Dolphin) if MPV is installed from Ubuntu Repositories.

---

A very good Lightly installation manual in YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIrYPFY25G4